# SWF extract to PNG

Tags: javascript, png, flash

I have an interactive .swf file with zooming and rotating. I want to be able to extract any of that "positions" to .png. I saw tools like swftools but it doesnt help since, as i understand, .swf itself has flashvars. Any ides on how i can achieve this. Command line solutions are preferred or javascript ones.